# Saving a Child class instance in a parent type variable and using the Child's functions through parent variable?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, liskov-substitution-principle

I have two classes called Bird and Eagle. The Eagle is inherits from the bird. Now, I can use the Bird Class to store an eagle type instance. However, when i try to call the function of eagle using the variable `a`    I get an error saying

> error: ‘class bird’ has no member named ‘attack’

How do i use the function attack ? Also, will it be the similar for typescript?

```
#include <stdio.h>

class bird{
    public:
    void fly(){
        printf("fly");
    }
};

class eagle: public bird{
    public:
    void attack(){
        printf("attack");
    }
};

int main()
{
    bird *a = new eagle();
    a->attack();



    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `a` is pointer to an object of type `bird`, so you're only allowed to call methods that are defined on the `bird` class. This makes sense - you can't treat all birds as eagles, after all.

You have a few options:

1. Don't call non-`bird` methods
2. Change the type of `a` to `eagle*`
3. Use `dynamic_cast` to hack around the issue (not recommended, this is usually a sign that you've modeled your data incorrectly)

```
dynamic_cast<eagle*>(a)->attack();
```

Documentation for `dynamic_cast`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast

Comment: how do i do the same thing in typescript ?

Comment: No idea, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can create virtual function attack in bird, which does nothing.

Then attack definition in eagle will override the base one.

```
virtual void attack() = 0;
```